# I want to Convert Object to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object like this:

```
var jsonObject = Object {transid: "104", amt: "750.00", dt: "2015-04-28 08:12:22", code: "11222", shop: "Joes Cafe"}
```

I tried converting it to an array like this:

```
var jsArray  =  Object.keys(jsonObject).map(function(k) { return jsonObject[k] });
```

and I get a result like this:

`["104", "750.00", "2015-04-28 08:12:22", "11222", "Joes Cafe"]`

But I want `jsArray` to be like this:

```
[{transid: "104", amt: "750.00", dt: "2015-04-28 08:12:22", code: "11222", shop: "Joes Cafe"}]
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: Please note that nothing you posted has anything to do with JSON. What you have is a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array, and insert your object into it.

```js
var array = [];
var jsonObject = {
  transid: "104",
  amt: "750.00",
  dt: "2015-04-28 08:12:22",
  code: "11222",
  shop: "Joes Cafe"
}
array.push(jsonObject);
document.write(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

It couldn't be simpler.

You actually don't have to *convert* anything here. You just have to create the array and add the object as element:

```
var arr = [obj]; // [ ] denotes an array literal in this case
```

[Learn more about arrays.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Array_object)

Comment: this makes the array multidimensional.  I want the array like the object. How do I do that?

Comment: @0808: this creates exactly what you claim you want. Not sure what you mean by "I want the array like the object.". Arrays and objects are two different data structures (conceptually). They are used for different purposes.